# At PostgreSQL, after recreating a function, is it necessary to drop existing triggers and recreate them?

Tags: postgresql

At PostgreSQL, if I have a function that is used by a trigger, when I update that function (with `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`) do I need to drop the trigger and recreate it?

Comment: no, you don't need to update the trigger.

the function is every time called

Comment: No, and you could/should have tested this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to drop and re-create triggers if you change the trigger function.